# Reorder li in order for ultiple ul-list with javascripts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to re-order several ul-list on my web.
Each ul with the same class should be in numerical order after using javascript.

The list may look like below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ul = $('ul.filelist');
  for (let u = 0; u < ul.length; u++) {
    const element = ul[u];

    li = element.querySelectorAll('li');

    li.detach().sort(function(a, b) {
      return $(a).data('sortby') - $(b).data('sortby');
    });

    u.append(li);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="filelist">
  <li data-sortby="3">3</li>
  <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
  <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
  <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="filelist">
  <li data-sortby="5">5</li>
  <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
  <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
  <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
</ul>
```

I want them show in order like

```html
<ul class="filelist">
  <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
  <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
  <li data-sortby="3">3</li>
  <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="filelist">
  <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
  <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
  <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
  <li data-sortby="5">5</li>
</ul>
```

But the error indicated that `li.detach` is not a function.
Could someone help me solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/#detach-selector) is a jQuery method, you're trying to apply it to NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery methods like `detach`, pass the selector to jQuery instead of `document.querySelectorAll`. In addition, you need to limit the scope of the selection to the current `<ul>` element rather than the whole document, which can be done by passing the context second argument.

For example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.filelist').each((i, el) => {
    $('li', el).detach().sort((a, b) => $(a).data('sortby') - $(b).data('sortby'))
        .appendTo(el);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filelist">
  <li data-sortby="3">3</li>
  <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
  <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
  <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="filelist">
  <li data-sortby="5">5</li>
  <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
  <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
  <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using sort method as follows.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".filelist").each(function() {
    const wrapper = $(this);
    wrapper
      .find("li")
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        const aVal = a.dataset.sortby;
        const bVal = b.dataset.sortby;
        return +aVal - +bVal;
      })
      .appendTo(wrapper);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul class="filelist">
     <li data-sortby="3">3</li>
     <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
     <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
     <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="filelist">
     <li data-sortby="5">5</li>
     <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
     <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
     <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery it can be a oneliner. The idea: sort a list of cloned list items of an ul on its data-sortby value, then replace the orgininal items.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`ul.filelist`)
  .forEach(ul => {
    const listItems = ul.querySelectorAll(`li[data-sortby]`);
    const sortedList = [...listItems]
      .map(item => item.cloneNode(true))
      .sort( (a, b) => +a.dataset.sortby - +b.dataset.sortby);
    listItems.forEach( (item, i) => item.replaceWith(sortedList[i]) )  
});
```

```html
<ul class="filelist">
     <li data-sortby="3">3</li>
     <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
     <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
     <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="filelist">
     <li data-sortby="5">5</li>
     <li data-sortby="2">2</li>
     <li data-sortby="1">1</li>
     <li data-sortby="4">4</li>
 </ul>
```